# How to integrate exponential function over implicit function

Tags: integral-equations

The following integral can be solved in Mathematica:

```
Integrate[Exp[a*(z - 1)], {x, y, z}\[Element]Sphere[],Assumptions -> a > 0 && a\[Element]Reals]
```

Outputs:

[image]

But if I change Sphere[] to implicit function, the integral can not be solved:

```
Integrate[Exp[a*(z - 1)], {x, y, z} \[Element] 
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, y, z}], 
 Assumptions -> a > 0 && a \[Element] Reals]
```

Furthermore, can this integral be solved over a spherical cap?

Comment: `Integrate[Exp[a*(z - 1)], {x, y, z} \[Element] Sphere[], 
 Assumptions -> a <=  0]` performs $\frac{4 \pi  e^{-a} \sinh (a)}{a}$ too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we need to use `ParametricRegion`.

```
reg2 = ParametricRegion[{Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
    Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
    Cos[ϕ]}, {{θ, 0, 2 π}, {ϕ, 0, π/4}}];
Integrate[Exp[a*(z - 1)], {x, y, z} ∈ reg2, 
 Assumptions -> a > 0]
(* Region[reg2, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, -.5}] *)
```

[image]
$$\frac{2 \pi  \left(1-e^{\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}-a}\right)}{a}$$

Comment: Something to adjust: the integrand is positive so does the integral, but  $$ \frac{2 \pi  \left(1-e^{\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}-a}\right)}{a}$$ is negative for big $a$.

Comment: @user64494, Please note that ` 1/Sqrt[2] -1< 0` so that the result is positive.

Comment: You are right, I amn't.